# What elements of .NET are missing in Mono?

Tags: c#, .net, mono

I mean library and syntax of C#.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the class library, ask the [Mono Class Library status page](http://www.go-mono.com/status/)

Answer (score 2):

C# 3.0 is supported fully.

C# 4.0 version [works](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2009/Aug-11.html) but [considered 'preview' until MS compiler is finalized](http://www.mono-project.com/CSharp_Compiler). There're even some [language extensions](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2009/Jul-27-1.html), although I doubt if they will be ever backported to MS compiler.

Comment: Not quite. If you look at the Mono status page, C# 3.0 is "mostly done".

Comment: Having a look at their bugtracker https://bugzilla.novell.com/index.cgi I've found few inconsistencies with MS C# compiler (including one introduced with .NET 3.5 SP1). But nevertheless you're right, thanks for your note.

Comment: I down-voted the original answer until it is inline edited with the clarification about 3.0 implementation being "mostly" not "fully" supported, as pointed out by Patrik

Answer (score 1):

You can view Mono's status updates (Like a Timeline, really), from their wiki.

[Mono Status Report](http://mono.wikia.com/wiki/Mono_status_report)

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at the [Mono Project Site](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) or at the [Wikipedia-Article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono_%28software%29#Current_status_and_roadmap).

But the last thing I heard is thet C# 3.0 is complete (except some LINQ-Features).

Answer (score 1):

There's a pretty in-depth analysis [here](http://codebetter.com/blogs/patricksmacchia/archive/2009/01/19/mono-vs-net-framework-public-api-compatibility.aspx) from January of this year.

The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono_%28software%29#Current_status_and_roadmap)'s "Current status and roadmap" looks helpful too.

Answer (score 1):

There's no equivalent of VT fixup or anything related to unmanaged exports for that matter.

That's not surprising, though. Considering that you would have a hard time using something looking like a Windows DLL as .so or .dylib. ;-)

I am not sure, but mixed-mode hasn't been supported a few years ago when I wanted to use it.
Maybe they added it, but I don't think so. Might be the big fat mother of all worm cans to open for an X platform CLI implementation.

Answer (score 1):

There are three aspects you need to consider.

1. Language
2. Framework
3. Runtime

**Language:**
Mono fully implements C# 2.0, and has almost complete support for 3.0. This means it supports all of the syntactical language features like generics, properties, anonymous methods/types, etc.
Mono supports Visual basic 8, but not 9.

**Framework:**
Mono fully implements ASP.NET and ADO.NET. Windows.Forms is mostly done.
WCF and WF are in progress.
WPF is not done, and is many years away from being done (if ever). I believe this is now a side project.
Linq-to-SQL is not yet finished.

**Runtime:**
The CLR has been almost fully implemented, including support for the DLR.

Your best two sources of information are probably the [Mono home page](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) (specifically the [FAQ](http://www.mono-project.com/FAQ:_General) and the [Status report](http://mono.wikia.com/wiki/Mono_status_report)), and the [Wikipedia page on Mono](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono_%28software%29#Current_status_and_roadmap).

Comment: The runtime is not fully implemented, tail calls do not work.

Comment: @Leppie. I'd call that a bug rather than not being implemented, but I've changed it to "almost fully implemented" just for you =;)